# Reverse engineering server seed

Tags: hash, sha256

```
$server_seed = "2754f7cc9e9e243711448401ea9d483067138a6b37c70c5d80b6c59943aa6996";

$lotto = "1135567382";

$round_id = "1";

$hash = hash("sha256", $server_seed . "-" . $lotto . "-" . $round_id);

$roll = hexdec(substr($hash, 0, 8)) % 15;

echo "Round $round_id = $roll";
```

This code generates a number using Server seed, Lotto and round ID. My question is, would it be possible to get the server seed if you only have RoundID, Lotto and the number that is generated?

Comment: "My question is, would it be possible to get the server seed if you only have RoundID, Lotto and the number that is generated?" All you need is the actual hash.  Why are you only taking a substring of the hash?  How: You try every possible hash and check it against the hash.

Comment: Multiple pairs of seed/lotto/round will generate the same roll value. So I swould say it's difficult.

Comment: It seems like you should also be worried about people predicting not-yet-released results, rather than just getting the server seed. ​ ​

Comment: Using HMAC would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be, no. In theory, hashes are one way functions, which means that you cannot use the output to learn any information about the input.

Since the server_seed is only presented post-hash, without finding a vulnerability in SHA-256 there is no way to get the server_seed.